# PHP check string for html

Tags: php

`$content` gives the html code like:

```
<p>text</p>
<p><img ... /></p>
<div class="video">...</div>
```

or just

```
<p>text</p>
<p>more text</p>
```

Also we have a variable:

```
$video_match = false;
```

We should turn `$video_match` to `true`, if `<div class="video">` (exactly this code) exists in `$content`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
if (strpos($content, '<div class="video">') !== FALSE)
{
  $video_match = true;
}
```

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

**Update:**

Or more compact version as shown in the comments below:

```
$video_match = (strpos($content, '<div class="video">') !== FALSE);
```

Comment: Simply this would do the job : $video_match = (strpos($content, '<div class="video">') !== FALSE);

Comment: `$video_match = (strpos($content, '<div class="video">') !== FALSE);`

Comment: @HoLyVieR: That's true but strictly it would return a number not true but anyway any number greater than 0 would still be considered true so yes that is a short way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: $video_match = (strpos($content, '<div class="video">');